# Is it possible to integrate Alexa voice service (AVS) to iOS app?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, avs

Surfed web but couldn't find any detailed document related to AVS integration with iOS app. Is Remote Authorisation is only allowed from iOS app? or else the app can behave like alexa (getting voice input and giving response)? Please share any useful document for better understanding.Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can integrate Alexa in iOS and Android devices . Please refer : https://superdevelopment.com/2017/02/06/adding-amazon-alexa-voice-services-to-your-ios-app-with-swift/  , https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-voice-service

Comment: @RohithKrishnan The sample project is missing in given link, I have a question that can we communicate with amazon echo device with ios app ?

Comment: Hi @Boobalan , do you mean amazon Alexa ??